# Make a sql function return multiple rows (table)

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am using MARIADB SQL, and I needed to create a function that returns specific rows from a table:

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getSpecificRows() RETURNS TABLE
    BEGIN
        RETURN (SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE visibility = 'public');
    END //
DELIMITER ;
```

However this gives error with TABLE as a return type.

Comment: Mariadb doesn't support "table" as  a type that can be returned by a function

Comment: Oh! So there is no way on doing soething similar?

Comment: No, but given the function you have described, why would you want to write this as a function, its easier to just incorporate the logic in a sql statement?

Comment: Due to application usage, the thing is that I need such statement to be run multiple times from different part of the code, so it would be useful if there was a way to pack such thing in a function like structure. Any ways thanks for the gidance.
Should I close now this post? Or instead put your anwser below so this might be useful for someone else.

Comment: Don't know it would help but you could create a View that encapsulates your logic - which would then be simple to query. Alternatively you could write a SP that saves the data out to a table that could then be queried

Comment: Is it at least able to return a single row? Or rows are considered also sort of tables?